# Custom navigationItem animation

Tags: iphone, animation, uinavigationitem

I want a custom animation on the leftBarButtonItem:

```
 UIBarButtonItem *menuButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Menu" 
                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                               target:self 
                               action:@selector(onMenuButtonTouch)];
viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuButton;
```

My UINavigationController pushes and pops views with a custom animation so the leftBarButtonItem doesn't have any animations at the moment.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:NO];
[UIView animateWithDuration:...
```

**-**

First I changed a property the see if it is animated but that didn't work. Then I tried to set the property before the animation starts but that didn't work either. It takes absolutely no effect.

Is there a way to animate something like this for example?

```
self.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.width = 10;
```

or

```
self.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.customView.alpha = 0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIBarButtonItem`s are not a subclass of `UIView` so you can't apply animations on them but `customView` is a `UIView` object so you can animate it.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                 animations:^{
                     self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.customView.alpha = 0;
                 }];
```

Comment: yes that works, thanks. My fault was that I called self.navigationController.navigationItem... instead of self.navigationItem...